# How to set a universal background for an application

Tags: android, eclipse, background

I am trying to set a background for every XML layout in my application, and I am using the same picture for them all. At the moment, I am going through all hundred or so layouts and just typing in the code:

```
android:background="@drawable/dirtwall"
```

Into all of the layouts. How would I be able to set it automatically so I wouldn't have to change other backgrounds as I made more, and so I wouldn't have to go through all of my XML files?

Also, I am using Eclipse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [styles](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/style-resource.html). This way, you can define all common elements in a single place and then update it only there.

Example `style.xml`, which should be located in your project's `/res/values/` folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="appearance">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/dirtwall</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

and use it like

```
<LinearLayout
    ...
    style = "@style/appearance"
>
```

Comment: what about the second part? the second block in your answer?

Comment: second part is any layout you want to apply style to.

Answer (score 0):

**Apply a theme to an Activity or application**

```
To set a theme for all the activities of your application, open the AndroidManifest.xml file and edit the <application> tag to include the android:theme attribute with the style name. For example:
```

---

```
<application android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">
```

---

```
If you want a theme applied to just one Activity in your application, then add the android:theme attribute to the <activity> tag instead.
```

---

```
if you want the background to be transparent, use the Translucent theme:
```

---

```
   <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent">
```

**here is the declaration for a custom theme which is simply the standard platforms default light theme. It would go in an XML file** under

```
res/values (typically res/values/styles.xml):
```

---

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    ...
</style>
```